# ASP.NET Core 3.0 can I use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

Can't find the answer. For example, can I use .NET Core 3 on Win7 with 4.5.2 .NET Framework or even lower (Win XP). Or can I use core without any preinstalled components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's .Net core 2.0, so I think net core 3.0 have to support the same system.

[image: img]

> Edit

[image]

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @evilGenius So, without any hesitations, I can download program with core and it'll work on this system, and I don't need to worry about installed frameworks?

Comment: @Interception I can't say it. I download it on windows 10 and i not faced any problem